# removing all words in a sentences with a specific symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to remove all the words in a sentence which starts with the symbol `$#` ,
for example if there is a sentence `I am $#trying to $#learn $regex for $#javascript`
I would want to remove the words trying , learn and javascript.. IS it possible to acheive through javascript regex??

Comment: Yes it is, but you'll learn more by trying it yourself. [This site helped me a lot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) when learning about regex

Comment: How do you wish to handle `I am $#trying to $#learn $regex, for java$#script!`?

Comment: @Jerry I would love to know two cases... 1) removing only when it comes at the start... 2) no mater which postion

Answer (score 1):

```
var sentence = "I am $#trying to $#learn $regex for $#javascript";
sentence = sentence.replace(/\$#[^\s]+/g, '');
// output: "I am  to  $regex for "
```

Comment: Will try this!! I got a helpful link from another person too on how to use regex.. thanks for the answer!! will update u if it works out!

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to trim string and duplicates of spaces in addition:

```
sentence = sentence
  .replace(/\s*\$#[^\s]+\s*/g, ' ')
  .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
;
// output: "I am to $regex for"
```